# How to Create a Multi Dimensional Array from arrays using loops or other methods in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, dynamic

I have 3 arrays, `$nos`, `$names` and `$marks`
as below

```
$nos = array("101","201","301","401");
$names = array("Jhon","Mike","Thomas","Stella");
$marks = array("65","35","25","45");
```

I want to create a multi dimensional array from these 3 arrays as below

```
$students = array(
    'Jhon' => [
        'number' => 101,
        'marks' => 65,
    ],
    'Mike' => [
        'number' => 201,
        'question' => 35,
    ],
   'Thomas' => [
        'number' => 301,
        'question' => 25,
    ],
   'Stella' => [
        'number' => 401,
        'question' => 45,
    ]
);
```

How to do this using loops or any other method in PHP, above 3 array size is not fixed.

Code I have tried

```
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($nos); $i++){ 
    $students = array( 
        $names[0] => [ 
            'number' => $nos[0], 
            'marks' => $marks[0], 
        ], 
    ); 
}
print_r($students);
```

Comment: Have you tried any code yet?  You mention using loops - which is a good start, but you need to try something.

Comment: also tried this

`for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($nos); $i++){  
$students = array(  
 $names[$i] => [  
        'number' => $nos[$i],  
        'marks' => $marks[$i],  
    ],  
);  

}  

print_r($students);`


output is :

`Array ( [Stella] => Array ( [number] => 401 [marks] => 45 ) )  `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference here is the way the results are added to the students array.  In your code you keep on adding the data to the same element (with the same data as you always use `[0]`.  Here the data is added using the name as the index and all arrays are reference with the loop index (`$i`)...

```
$students = [];
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($nos); $i++){
    $students[$names[$i]] = [ 'number' => $nos[$i],
        'marks' => $marks[$i]];
}
print_r($students);
```